# Several cores writing in a single file?

Tags: c++, file, stream

I've been coding a multi-thread simulation storing the outputs in files. So far, I've assigned one file to core (with a `ofstream myfiles[NUMBER_OF_CORES]`) from the beginning but it's a bit messy as I'm working with several computers having 20+ cores. I've been doing that to avoid overheading if using one file, but could I use something like a stream per core and in the end, use something like:

```
for(int i =0; i < NUMBER_OF_CORES; i++){
  myfile << CORE_STREAM[i];
  }
```

starting with a `CORE_STREAM[NUMBER_OF_CORES]` array? I've never manipulated streams in this way. Which class should I construct this from if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ostringstream` to store intermediate results in memory. Like `ofstream`, it implements the `ostream` interface so your existing code probably will work as-is.

To dump one stream on another, you'd do `myfile << core_stream[i].rdbuf()`. = Read Buffer

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) pipeline?  Your simulation threads could write to a ZMQ_PUSH socket (see [zmq_socket(3)](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket)) and whatever is writing to the file (another thread or process, ZMQ doesn't care) could read from a ZMQ_PULL socket.  That way your simulation threads can potentially get out of doing any blocking IO without staging results in memory.  I can't imagine working on a distributed computing project these days and not using ZMQ.